# How can I deal with accented letters, german letters and other characters?

Tags: python, unicode

My python script is working now, but I'm having a little trouble:

Here is the output:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

langCode={
    "arabic":"ar", "bulgarian":"bg", "chinese":"zh-CN",
    "croatian":"hr", "czech":"cs", "danish":"da", "dutch":"nl",
    "english":"en", "finnish":"fi", "french":"fr", "german":"de",
    "greek":"el", "hindi":"hi", "italian":"it", "japanese":"ja",
    "korean":"ko", "norwegian":"no", "polish":"pl", "portugese":"pt",
    "romanian":"ro", "russian":"ru", "spanish":"es", "swedish":"sv" }

def setUserAgent(userAgent):
    urllib.FancyURLopener.version = userAgent
    pass

def translate(text, fromLang, toLang):
    setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070400 SUSE/3.0.1-0.1 Firefox/3.0.1")
    try:
        postParameters = urllib.urlencode({"langpair":"%s|%s" %(langCode[fromLang.lower()],langCode[toLang.lower()]), "text":text,"ie":"UTF8", "oe":"UTF8"})
    except KeyError, error:
        print "Currently we do not support %s" %(error.args[0])
        return

    page = urllib.urlopen("http://translate.google.com/translate_t", postParameters)
    content = page.read()
    page.close()

    htmlSource = BeautifulSoup(content)
    translation = htmlSource.find('span', title=text )
    return translation.renderContents()


print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "German")
print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "Italian")
print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "Spanish")

Guten Morgen, du Freund!
Buongiorno a te amico!
Buenos dÃ­as a ti amigo!
```

How do I manage the letters that aren't basic english letters? How would you recommend I solve this? I was thinking a dictionary to replace certain chains with another character, but I'm sure Python has something like this already. Batteries included and whatnot. :P

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse `http://translate.google.com/translate_t` since Google provides an AJAX service for this purpose. The `translatedText` in the `json` data returned by `ajax.googleapis.com` is already a unicode string.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import sys
import json

LANG={
    "arabic":"ar", "bulgarian":"bg", "chinese":"zh-CN",
    "croatian":"hr", "czech":"cs", "danish":"da", "dutch":"nl",
    "english":"en", "finnish":"fi", "french":"fr", "german":"de",
    "greek":"el", "hindi":"hi", "italian":"it", "japanese":"ja",
    "korean":"ko", "norwegian":"no", "polish":"pl", "portugese":"pt",
    "romanian":"ro", "russian":"ru", "spanish":"es", "swedish":"sv" }

def translate(text,lang1,lang2):
    base_url='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?'    
    langpair='%s|%s'%(LANG.get(lang1.lower(),lang1),
                      LANG.get(lang2.lower(),lang2))
    params=urllib.urlencode( (('v',1.0),
                       ('q',text.encode('utf-8')),
                       ('langpair',langpair),) )
    url=base_url+params
    content=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    try: trans_dict=json.loads(content)
    except AttributeError:
        try: trans_dict=json.load(content)    
        except AttributeError: trans_dict=json.read(content)
    return trans_dict['responseData']['translatedText']

print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "German")
print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "Italian")
print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "Spanish")
```

yields

```
Guten Morgen, du Freund!
Buongiorno a te amico!
Buenos días a ti amigo!
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help! I didn't know they offered JSON, I'll look into this as well. When running your example, I get the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TranslateMyPyAjax\src\translatemypyajax.py", line 35, in <module>
    print translate("Good morning to you friend!", "English", "Spanish")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: It's translating german and italian correctly, but not the spanish, I'm guessing because of the accented i.

Comment: @Sergio: I think this might be an error that affects Windows users when trying to print unicode to a Windows console. See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console/2013263#2013263 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789924/python-os-walk-and-japanese-filename-crash/3791196#3791196 helps.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the proper charset from the headers returned by `urlopen()` and pass it as the `fromEncoding` argument to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor.